# Convert LongBits to float in python3

Tags: java, python, python-3.x

I am trying to replicate the following java code in python3. It converts a long to a float.

```
value = Double.longBitsToDouble(Long.parseLong("-4677979004942286848"))
> -7.812499999992895E-5
```

However, there seems to be no equivalent in pythons `float()`.

**EDIT**

The original value is created by calling the code below in java.

```
longbits = Double.doubleToLongBits(double_value)
```

Comment: Arn't long integers in Python 3.x just integers? so they aren't a separate numeric object anymore just and integer with infinite length. So float() should just work fine.[Integer Objects in python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/c-api/long.html)
But I might just don't understand it right.

Comment: @GittingGud OP wants to obtain the `float` with the same underlying **bit values**, not the same decimal value.

Comment: @GittingGud sadly no, float(-4677979004942286848) --> -4.677979004942287e+18 !=  -7.812499999992895E-5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in Python library [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) and can do that ([considering the size of a `long`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters) on your machine):

```
import struct
longint_binary = struct.pack('q', -4677979004942286848)  
struct.unpack('d', longint_binary)[0] # >> -7.812499999992895e-05
```

Comment: This works for me and Python 3.7, what are you using?

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters) says the standard size of `long` is 4 bytes. You should use format string `'q'` (`long long`) instead to ensure that the conversion works on other platforms.

Comment: Thanks for the addition, @meowgoesthedog. The questions was regarding long only, but you are completely right. I added your remark to my answer.

Comment: @MichaelDorner "long" isn't a type in Python. `int` is used for all integer types and its size can be arbitrary. The C `long` type can have different sizes depending on the platform, which you must take steps to guard against.